# Variable with symbol (-)

Tags: php

A have a variable with a `-`. When I run my script I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='`.

This is the following line:

```
$selected-text = $_POST['faco'] ;
```

How can I write this script without changing the variable name?

Comment: You can't. That is an invalid [variable name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a legitimate question, well posed, even if the answer seems trivial to most.

Answer (score 0):

The "-" character is a reserved operator in PHP and can't be used in variable names.  Use an underscore instead:

```
`$selected_text = $_POST['faco'];`
```

In PHP a valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*' (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)